# javascript now to create two ways currency format?

Tags: javascript, html

I have found this link have a simple and useable funciton to convert number to currency.

[www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html](http://www.mredkj.com/javascript/nfbasic.html)

but how to turn it back form currency to number...

I already try this :

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/vb2cb1tm/3/]...
```

But its failed...

I try to read a formatted string using javascript and make a counting on this valua...

Comment: but it's completely diferent in all aspect it's about input and output in html, control using js

Answer (score 0):

```
function cur2num(cur) {
  return parseFloat(cur.replace(/,/g,"");
}
```

if currency signs try `/[^0-9]\.\-]/g` as first argument to the replace

Answer (score 0):

I think something as simple as

```
function numbers(nStr){
    return Number(nStr.replace(/[\$\,]/g,''));
}
```

might do the trick, though it's hard to tell without seeing your original code.